# read the data and skip parenthese with scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I write a C program to pick the data from the the std input, which starts with a number  indicating the number of the data sets, then there are N pairs of data, in the form: (x y), so I write the code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n_sets;
    scanf("%d", &n_sets);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n_sets; ++i)
    {
        int m, n;
        scanf("(%d %d)", &m, &n);
        printf("%d\t%d\n", m, n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work. After I input the number of the data set, the program print the uninitialized m&n directly. But when I add a space before the `(%d %d)`, it works fine. Somebody can explain this?

Comment: 1. Check the return value from `scanf` 2. Use a debugger to find out what is going wrong

Comment: This reminds me to `fflush()`..

Comment: @Lucio: from what I remember, fflush on stdin is a Microsoft-only extension.

Comment: I think that him could be using Windows.

Comment: @Lucio It's platform independent. Linux and windows have the same result. I wasn't clear about the behavior of scanf(). verbose's answer explain that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have character literals in your argument to `scanf()`, it expects to find those literals exactly as specified in the format string.

```
scanf("%d", &n_sets);
```

correctly reads `n_sets`, and stops at the newline or other whitespace character in the buffer. The next `scanf()` :

```
scanf("(%d %d)", &m, &n);
```

expects to find an open parenthesis at the beginning of the input, but finds a whitespace character instead. So it fails, and `scanf()` returns without having read anything. Consequently, your `m` and `n` remain uninitialized, and garbage results.

When you put in the space before the open parenthesis like so:

```
scanf(" (%d %d)", &m, &n);
```

it tells `scanf()` to skip any leading whitespace before the parenthesis in the input buffer, so the program works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
scanf("%d", &n_sets);
```

to

```
scanf("%d\n", &n_sets);
```

and input your n_sets ending up with a [enter], it works.

[image]

Comment: See the answer above from verbose. He explains very good what exactly happen.

Comment: FYI: Changing "%d" to "%d\n" or "%d " or "%d\t", etc. will have the same effect.  In each case the whitespace character in the format will match _any_ whites space.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your input is like this:

```
2 (1 2) (3 4)
```

There is a space(or new line?) after the first number, so change the `scanf` in the loop to:

```
scanf("\n(%d %d)", &m, &n);
//     ^^
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the input into the program has some amount of whitespace before the value you want scanf to parse.  The space in the string tells scanf to ignore whitespace.  Without it, scanf is looking for an exact match immediately.